# Loading a dictionary from a navigation bar title

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uinavigationbar, nsdictionary

I have a mainViewController which pushes a detailViewController onto the screen. 
The items (images, navigation bar title, textview, and a button) in the detailViewController are all loaded from an NSMutableDictionary in the MainViewController depending on which image in it is tapped.

I also have a button in the detailViewController that when selected loads a mapview which shows the user's location.  When the user taps a button a pin is dropped marking this location with a annotation callout title.

I want the title of the mapview and the annotation title to be the same as the detailViewController's which is loaded from the MainViewController's NSMutableDictionary.

Right now I am trying to use the detailViewController's title as the determining factor in the mapview's title and annotation title.  However this isn't working.

Here is my code in MainViewController .m.

```
- (void) coverflowView:(TKCoverflowView*)coverflowView coverAtIndexWasDoubleTapped:(int)index{

    SomeDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SomeDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ((int)index == 0) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"0002.jpg", @"imagekey",
                        @"This is tree 0002", @"textkey", 
                        @"0002.image.png",@"imagekey2",
                        @"0002 title", @"headerkey",
                        @"www.0003.com", @"address",nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey2"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"address"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey"]);
         detailViewController.myDictionary = myDictionary;
    }

    else if ((int)index == 1) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"0003.jpg", @"imagekey",
                                             @"This is 0003", @"textkey", 
                                             @"0003.image.png",@"imagekey2",
                                             @"0003 title", @"headerkey",
                                             @"www.0003.com", @"address",nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey2"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"address"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey"]);
        detailViewController.myDictionary = myDictionary;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Here is my code in the detailViewController.m.
This loads my Dictionary strings (The bold part is loading the navigation bar title).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *filePath =[self pathOfFile];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        myText.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:app];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    imageView .image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey"]];

    imageView2 .image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.imageView2.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey2"]];

    self.myText.text =[(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"];

    **self.navigationItem.title = [(NSMutableDictionary *)myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey"];**
    NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imagekey2"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"textkey"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [myDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey"]);
}
```

Here is where I am trying to load the navigation bar title and annotation title using the current navigation bar title as the determining factor.
This is the only thing I can think of to use since there is no stable element.  Everything in the detailViewController is loaded from the MainViewController NSDictionary.

```
 -(IBAction)pushMap:(id) sender{

    SomePositionViewController *somePosition = [[SomePositionViewController alloc] init]; 


    if ((self.navigationItem.title = @"0002 title")) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mapDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              @"0002a title", @"headerkey2",
                                             @"0002 annotation title", @"titlekey",nil];
        treePosition.mapDictionary = mapDictionary;
        NSLog(@"%@", [mapDictionary objectForKey:@"titlekey"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [mapDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey2"]);
    }

   else if((self.navigationItem.title = @"0003 title")) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mapDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              @"0003a title", @"headerkey2",
                                              @"0003 annotation title", @"titlekey",nil];
        treePosition.mapDictionary = mapDictionary;
        NSLog(@"%@", [mapDictionary objectForKey:@"titlekey"]);
       NSLog(@"%@", [mapDictionary objectForKey:@"headerkey2"]);
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:somePosition animated:YES];    

                                                }
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?  I have been wracking my brain but to no avail.  HELP!

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but: In the pushMap method, `if ((self.navigationItem.title = @"0002 title"))` is wrong.  First, the single `=` sign does an assignment.  The double `==` is for checking equality.  Second, to check _NSString_ equality you must use `isEqualToString:` (eg. `if ([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"0002 title"])`).

Answer (score 0):

One thing I spotted is that you are comparing strings the wrong way. You use

```
if ((self.navigationItem.title = @"0002 title"))
```

but should use

```
if (([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString:@"0002 title"]))
```

Comparing strings in your way will always fail.

Comment: Sorry, Tried this and it doesn't work.  I think for some reason using the title as a variable doesn't work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd have two suggestions. First, set breakpoints in your code and inspect what's actually contained in your variables. You may be able to find out what's going wrong. Second, use the more normal way of providing a detail view with data - create an instance variable in the detail view (for example, "placeTitle") and when you create the detail view in the parent view, set that variable to what you want it to be. Trying to use the title of the navigation item should work, but it's a strange way to do this.